# php function for matching

Tags: php, match, matching

I am looking for function which does this option:

```
preg_match("/^{$STRING}/i", ...)
```

but, without regular expression, and there must be the `^` in the first, which means that this expression will be false:

```
$search = "hi", $search_in "ahi";
```

it must be at the start of the string.

Comment: Question 1: what's wrong with regex?  Question 2: did you mean to have curly braces in there?  With curly braces in place, your regex will very likely be invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understood your request well... But... Try this:

```
/** Checks if a target string (haystack) starts with a specified string (needle) */
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return (stripos($haystack, $needle) === 0);
}

/* Usage */
startsWith("ahi", "hi"); // Returns FALSE
startsWith("ahi", "ah"); // Returns TRUE
```

Please note that you need to use 3 `=` signs, because the function will return false when there is no match in the string.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if(stripos($search_in, $search) === 0) {
  echo "matched";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stripos($haystack, $needle) === 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The *exact* function for that purpose is [`strncasecmp`](http://php.net/strncasecmp). I have no idea why everyone is so bent on `stripos` workarounds recently.

Albeit it needs the string length for comparison, and the result must be negated for positive matches

```
if (!strncasecmp($string, "search", 6)) {
```

The advantage is that it really only compares the first 6 characters. It does not search the whole subject and require an extra comparison afterwards. (Stupid if used as microoptimization. But it's the exact function for that task.)

Comment: Maybe use $haystack, $needle, strlen($needle).

Answer (score 0):

```
function startsWithi($haystack, $needle)
{
    return substr(strtolower($haystack), 0, strlen($needle))) === $needle;
}
```

Comment: You need case sensitivity on both strings

Comment: strtolower(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === strtolower($needle)